# how to load model on HMVC with CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, module, hmvc

I am using the libraries for the HMVC, I am using CI 2.1 and I just cannot start with basic things, could anybody tell me how to load the model of the controller when I work as modules?

I read this docs https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home and I created the config/routes file.

**Controller:**

```
class Testcase extends MX_Controller {
   function index()
   {
      echo "test1";
      $this->load->model('testcase/testcase_model');
      echo "test2";
   }
}
```

I used the "echo" to see where it fails, because it doesnt return me any error... so, when I load the module, it simply doesn't work, I also tried it this way

```
$this->load->model('testcase_model',NULL,TRUE);
```

but still no success...

**Model:**

```
class Testcase_model extends MX_Model {
   function __construct(){  
      parent::__construct();  
   }    

   function testcase(){
      return "success";
   }
}
```

When I install the library I copy the third party folder and in the core one.

Could anybody give me some clue for this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: the version of the HMVC is the 5.4

Comment: what is the folder structure of your module? To me it looks fine.. May be its not getting the right path to load the classes.

Comment: The structure is application/modules/testcase/  controllers/testcase  models/testcase_model and views/testcase_view

Comment: @Philip is correct.. I totally forgot that.. Your Model should extend CI_Model :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no MX_Model that I am aware of, simply extend CI_Model.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
$this->load->model('YOUR_MODULE_FOLDER_NAME/MODEL_NAME');
```

to load you external model.

Answer (score 1):

In HMVC your files/folders should have following structure :

```
application/modules/testcase
 controllers
  testcase
 models
  testcase_model
 views
  testcase_view
```

if you are loading the model from within your module controller, you should load it like this

```
$this->load->model('testcase/testcase_model','tm');
```

You should give the module name as well. If not it will look in application/models directory.

Comment: Thanks, the structure is the same... and I tried naming the controller..  still no working... should i configure something extra in the version 5.4?

Answer (score 0):

For CI+HMVC I load load modules this:

```
$this->load->model('model_name');
$this->model_name->method($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update modules/Testcase/models/Testcase_model.

```
class Testcase_model extends CI_Model {

  function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }
   function get_login(){
     $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM test");
     return $query;
   }

}
```

and call from module controller

```
$this->load->model('Testcase/Testcase_model');
$data['result']=$this->Testcase_model->get_login();
```

Hope this help :)